# + /opt/wildfly/bin/jboss-cli.sh controller=10.91.12.91 -c --user=**** --password=**** '--commands=deploy dist/NewFaveo.war --force' undefined

Tags: wildfly

WFLYCTL0063: Composite operation was rolled back

- /opt/wildfly-23.0.2.Final/bin/jboss-cli.sh controller=10.91.12.91 -c --user=**** --password=**** '--commands=deploy dist/NewFaveo.war --force'

Comment: Do you have more details than this? What version of WildFly? Do you see errors in the server logs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.